# Como buscar un dato especifico con AXIOS en una base de datos mysql? React App

Tags: mysql, reactjs, axios, get, next.js

Tengo una aplicacion en react, donde quiero implementar un buscador de pedidos, quiero buscar un numero de pedido desde el lado del cliente. Pero tengo la duda si tengo que cargar todos los pedidos de la aplicacion en la api para despues buscar el pedido en la API, o es posible pasar el dato por axios a una funcion GET en la API para que se busque unicamente ese dato en la base de datos.

En otras palabras, me gustaria entender si todos los pedidos tienen que estar cargados en la API siempre, o si es posible no tenerlos cargados en la API y solo buscar el pedido especifico en la base de datos por medio de axios.get.

realmente mi problema esta cuando quiero enviar el id del pedido buscado desde el front end mediante el axios.get(url, numeroDepedidoBuscado), no encuentro la forma de ya cuando estoy en el backend leer esa constante de "numeroDePedidoBuscado"

const res = axios.get(url, numeroDePedidoBuscado)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Entonces, tu problema no es lo que describis, si no como pasar por axios a un get escrito en ¿node? parametros.. si es un get, va en el querystring... pero reformula tu pregunta, porque si, tenes que recibir el id e ir y buscarlo...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.